# Android GO button capture using javascript

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, form-submit

I am developing a mobile website. I need to capture "GO" button of android keypad using javascript or jquery. I guess "GO" key is same as ENTER key, so I was using the javascript code that captured ENTER key press event. The code works perfectly on desktop/notebook  and iPhone browsers but on android browser it submits the page to itself and page reloads. Please note that android browser was behaving in same way even before I captured any key press event and page does not have any button of type submit.

Thank you
Shubhra

Comment: While testing on android, I found that javascript for key press event is working correctly. But instead of remaining on the same page, android browser reloads the page and as a result all the entered values in textboxes disappear. If I press back button on my android phone it shows me the same page, with all the values that I had entered. Can anyone suggest a way out for this?

Comment: Please can somebody suggest me a wayout for this, so that the page don't get refreshed each time  use press "GO" key ?

Comment: if you are using a form try using $("#formid").submit(); this should do the trick.

Comment: I have tried this, it works in all the browser except android.

Comment: whats the javascript code ur using?

Comment: `function catchEnterKeyEvent(e) {
    var key;
    if (window.event) {
        key = window.event.keyCode;     //IE
    }
    else {
        key = e.which;
    }
    if (key == 13)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}`                                                                   Calling this function on onKeyDown event of a inputbox and if function returns true i submit the form. I have even tried $("form").submit() of jquery but no help.